# Saving mpf_t value to file using MPIR (GMP) library

Tags: c, file, save, gmp, mpir

I am trying to save my number in a file but the program keeps crashing:

```
include stdio.h
include mpir.h

int main(void){

mpf_set_default_prec(32); //Default precision for floating points

mpf_t my_number;
mpf_init_set_str(my_number, "5.12345e0", 10); //Set my_number to 5.123 with decimal base (10)

FILE *f;
f = fopen("some.txt", "w");

gmp_printf("Printed number to screen: %.*Ff \n", 32, my_number);

//Everything works until I try to save it to file:

gmp_fprintf(f, "My saved number is:  %.*Ff \n", 32, my_number);

fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```

Instead of fprintf i tried:

> gmp_fscanf(f, "%F", &zbroj)
>
> mpz_out_str(f, 10, zbroj)
>
> sprintf(f, "%F", zbroj)

Comment: Please note that you're leaking memory by not calling `mpf_clear(my_number)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was something wrong with my x64 build. 
I compiled MPIR again (this time x32) and put files to VS directory and it worked.

My guess is that there are special instructions for building x64 that I did not follow :\

Btw. I used 
    mpf_out_str(f, 10, 0, var);

Where f is pointer to file, 10 is base, 0 means maximum precision and var is variable that will be saved.